# In Rails 4 disable Strong Parameters by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Is there anyway to disable using strong params?

And I know it's a security vulnerability but I really don't need it / want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "disable" you mean falling back to Rails 3-style `attr_accessible` lines, then yes.

Just use the [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem.

Answer (score 48):

Turning off attribute protection is almost always a bad idea.

With that obligatory note out of the way, here's how to turn it off:

```
config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true
```

Place this in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't work for me (on a Rails 4.0.0 app).

Comment: Worked for me. Agreed - it's generally a bad idea - but my use case is an admin site where admins can change anything.

Comment: It worked for me. Be sure to put the line inside your Application class and reboot the HTTP server.

Comment: This tip is invaluable when migrating an older (Rails 3.2) app and trying to get to get the existing specs working as a first pass at the migration, before going through the job of reworking every single model and controller to use the new mass assignment protection approach adopted in Rails 4.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem where I was trying to store all the params from a webhook from Stripe.

If you want to allow all parameters for a single instance, your can call #to_hash on your params object before passing it into your initialize method.

Ex:

```rb
@my_object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object].to_hash)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

DHH comments [here on this pull request to add a disable switch to strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/pull/55)

> All this is a legacy concern anyway soon as Rails 4.0 will force strong parameters on everyone and you won't be able to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

to stop the forbidden attributes being checked for your applications you can patch out the check ..

for example put the following code in

config/initializers/disable_strong_parameters.rb

```
module ActiveModel
  module ForbiddenAttributesProtection
    protected
      def sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes)
          attributes
      end
      alias :sanitize_forbidden_attributes :sanitize_for_mass_assignment
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can! According to Strong Parameters's official Docs(https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), you can disable by adding below codes to your config/application.rb:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

It works for me in rails 3.2

Comment: this is to disable protected_attributes